# What should have happened to make Arduino.SE a real SE site?

Tags: discussion, area-51, private-beta, closed-sites

What sort of things were overlooked by the community that caused this site to fall short?

[Here's a screenshot of the original "Arduino.SE is closing" post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emcjD.jpg)

Also relevant: [What should be the scope of the Arduino site?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9112/what-should-be-the-scope-of-the-arduino-site) , [What's wrong with EE?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9084/whats-wrong-with-ee), [Differences with EE](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9969/differences-with-ee)

Answer (score 11):

The main issues were/are :

- We had 40 questions on day one and about 5/day after that which is very low for a private beta.
- Visits/day have been dropping since day one. (They have increased since yesterday)
- We have had just 5 people sign up in the past 3 days, which means users have not been inviting others to participate which is critical to site success
- The site has not been active as it could have been in terms of improving content and meta participation

I personally believe that the site should have been given a warning, and then some time to tackle these problems, however, that did not happen. Nonetheless, we created some excellent content, that will find a home on EE now.

Answer (score 5):

> This is *our* screw-up, not yours. When we were debating whether to send this site into beta, [I voiced some concern that there was a lot of overlap in the definition](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9218/if-this-isnt-a-duplicate-of-ee-might-want-to-consider-elevating-fewer-electron). After some debate internally, we decided to go ahead with the launch, thinking there would be enough interest in other Arduino topics to carry the site. We were wrong. However, I still think this site *does* demonstrate that there is a wealth of knowledge that hasn't necessarily found a place within EE.

I do feel that it is (at least partly) our screwup, but that's not the reason I'm quoting this.

Basically, being a subset scope-wise, we had much higher standards to live up to. It was uncertain if we would even have *had* a private beta, so once we had one, we should have put more effort into proving that it would work. Our questions/day were rather low -- on its own this should not have been a problem, as Chem.SE had similar stats in its private beta. However, we also had a very small group of answerers, and we had low views.

I don't know what we *could* have done. Some of us delayed answering to let others answer, but that didn't work much. (Also, on other private betas it is quite common to have 4-5 answers on good questions. Here we had just 1-2). I guess this was just a general problem with the community; only a few had immediate questions to ask. It could also be that Arduino.cc and Google manage to solve most Arduino questions one has, and the site just wouldn't have worked as a private beta.

Comment: I don't know that this was necessarily part of any screw up on ***anyone's*** part. This is all part of a process; a vetting of ideas. You work your way through the phases to see how far the idea can go. It's just that this *particular* idea wasn't meant to be. It got further than most.

Comment: @RobertCartaino: Of course, but there probably were things we could have done better :)

Comment: I really am not sure how much EE would *really* accept these questions, as much as some argue they would...